# Learning Laravel Basic: Post Method Problem

Tags: php, laravel, post

So, I am trying to redirect the page from login.blade.php into halamanUtama.blade.php with a button in a form, but somehow it always shows page expired. I don't know why. Here is my source code:

login.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Login</title>

 <!--CSS-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" type="text/css">
</head>
 <body>
  <div class="login-page-frame">
    <div class="header-login-page-frame">
        <h3>Login</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-login-form-frame">
        <form method="post" action="./home" class="login-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="login-username">
            <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="pass" name="login-password">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-login">Log In</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
 return view('login');
});

Route::post('/home', 'loginController@index');
```

loginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class loginController extends Controller
{
  //
  public function index(){
    return view("halamanUtama");
  }

}
```

halamanUtama.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Halaman Utama</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   Selamat datang
 </body>
</html>
```

Please help.

Comment: what are you doing? Just click login without username and password it want to go you required page.

Comment: Missing a `@csrf` in your form

Comment: @Dev actually, I'm trying to make a login form, but I thought I just make sure first that I can at least redirect it correctly and this happened

Comment: @kerbholz do you mean {{ csrf_field }}?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf Depending on what version of Laravel you're using either `@csrf` or `{{ csrf_field }}`, yes

Comment: @kerbholz I tried it and it works. thanks. I thought it is just for something like security function so I don't really read it first

Answer (score 0):

check this steps:

- your login route is better to be get
- check your directory in resource/views
- your submit form
- ...

have a look on tutorials like [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-and-easy-laravel-login-authentication), etc...

Comment: Thanks for the reference, looks great since it also explain about migrations